# Finding route with HERE offline

Tags: android, here-api

I want to find a route with HERE but offline.
The target of the route should be human readable text (like Berlin) and not latitude/longitude values.
Now I'm using RoutePlan class which requires lat/long values, and I'm using Geocoder to translate readable text to lat/long values.
But in offline mode (no WiFi, no Cellular Data) I can't use Geocoder to get the lat/long of a place.
How nonetheless can I use HERE maps in offline mode to find a route?

Comment: You can't.. I'm guessing

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the HERE android SDK? If so, you most certainly can.

What you need are two things:

1: Download some maps via our MapLoader APIs.

2: Set MapsEngine#setOnline(false) to change the engine to offline only mode.

Geocoding will work offine if the data is downloaded. Routing, guidance and and map rendering will work too.

Comment: Hi @David, I have downloaded maps and setting maps engine as false but while drawing route insufficient_map_data error is getting.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to David Leong's answer, I had to use HERE's GeocodeRequest instead of Geocoder to get the latitude and longitude.
Example at https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-starter/topics/geocoding.html